# Insert JSON object into an existing JSON object as a key-value-pair in Boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

I have a class hierarchy that looks like this: class A is composed of classes B and C.
B and C each have a function that returns boost::json::object, which looks like this in case of B: `{"B": "someValue"}`

A is supposed to compose each of these objects into a structure like this:

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": "someValue",
    "C": "someOtherValue"
  }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is, that the resulting object always looks like this:

```
{
  "A": [
    { "B": "someValue" },
    { "C": "someOtherValue" }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the objects from the subclasses are not added as key-value pairs, but as objects, each containing a single pair, into an array.

Here's a snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/json.hpp>

using namespace boost::json;

object makeObject(std::string key, int value)
{
    object obj;
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    object obj;
    obj["main"] = {makeObject("test1", 123), makeObject("test2", 456)};

    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

According to the Quick Look documentation of boost, I would have expected this to not create an array with single-value objects in it.
What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I modified my example based on sehe's answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/json.hpp>

auto makeProp(string_view name, value v)
{
    return object::value_type(name, std::move(v));
}

int main() {
    object obj;
    obj["main"] = {makeProp("test1", 123), makeProp("test2", 456)};

    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this still generates undesired output, unless I made a mistake:

```
{"main":[["test1",123],["test2",456]]}
```

To elaborate further on my usecase for the helper function, I originally intended for this to be a quick writeup to recreate the issue I described with my class hierarchy above.

I made a longer program that shows the issue in a more understandable way hopefully:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::json;

class B
{
public:
    key_value_pair makeProp()
    {
        value v = {"property1", 1};
        return object::value_type("B", std::move(v));
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    key_value_pair makeProp()
    {
        value v = {{"property1", 1}, {"property2", {1, 2, 3}}};
        return object::value_type("C", std::move(v));
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    object makeProp()
    {
        B b;
        C c;

        object obj;
        obj["A"] = {b.makeProp(), c.makeProp()};
        return obj;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a.makeProp() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this explains why I added the helper function, and makes it clearer what I want to achieve.

This returns:

```
{
  "A": [
    [
      "B",
      [
        "property1",
        1
      ]
    ],
    [
      "C",
      {
        "property1": 1,
        "property2": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

While I would have expected:

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "property1": 1
    },
    "C": {
      "property1": 1,
      "property2": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeObject` returns single objects. You pass them as the initializer list to a `json::value`, so you **should** expect `{makeObject(...), makeObject(...)}` to create an array: [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__value/value/overload35.html)

> If the initializer list consists of key/value pairs, an object is created. Otherwise an array is created.

Instead, you want to make an initializer list of key-value pair, not objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for COLIRU

namespace json = boost::json;

int main() {
    // construct:
    json::object obj{
        {"main",
         {
             {"test1", 123},
             {"test2", 456},
         }},
    };

    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    // update:
    obj["main"] = {{"B", "someValue"}, {"C", "someOtherValue"}};
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51859f5dda8dc4ef)**:

```
{"main":{"test1":123,"test2":456}}
{"main":{"B":"someValue","C":"someOtherValue"}}
```

### BONUS

If you /need/ to have the helper function for some reason:

```
auto makeProp(std::string_view name, json::value v) {
    return json::object::value_type(name, std::move(v));
}
```

Comment: I edited my original question, because I feel like I left out some important information. Hopefully it's become clear now. Could you maybe take another look?

Comment: Oh. I just realized that Boost JSON is doing magic with `initializer_list<value_ref>` instead of taking `object::value_type`. Sadly, it will not (ever) work with a helper function because it will require you to store an initializer list of `value_ref` which leads to undefined behaviour (hinted at [in the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__value_ref.html#json.ref.boost__json__value_ref.remarks:~:text=Never%20declare%20a%20variable%20of%20type%20std%3A%3Ainitializer_list%20except%20in%20function%20parameter%20lists)).

Comment: How about http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4e811f8e281ab51  Also keep in mind Boost JSON has this functionality built in (but generalized): https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/json/doc/html/json/dom/conversion.html

Comment: Demonstrating the builtin `value_to` and `value_from` mechanism: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6846522c1c10569 Note the subtle shift from named-object to just-object.  I think that's strictly more useful anyways. `struct A { B b1, b2; }` should probably not get two nodes both named the same anyways.

Comment: These solutions look promising, I think I can adapt my code to work as expected now. Thanks again, I'll mark this answer as accepted :)